React Native - UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance warning
I'm learning React Native with Expo, and I am currently at the 'React Navigation' stage where I am encountering a problem.
I haven't messed with the status bar yet, but I get the following warning:
If you want to change the appearance of status bar, you have to change     UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance key in the Info.plist to YES

I tried to do that in the app.json file by adding in the ios key:
"infoPlist": {
    "UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance": true
}

but it did not resolve the problem.
Here are the full logs:
If you want to change the appearance of status bar, you have to change     UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance key in the Info.plist to YES

RNScreens::RNScreensTurboModule::getPropertyNames(facebook::jsi::Runtime&)
    RNSScreenWindowTraits.mm:18
RCTViewManagerModuleNameForClass
RCTViewManagerModuleNameForClass
RCTViewManagerModuleNameForClass
3A5F992A-D1CD-312E-BD2E-F7C66343A417
3A5F992A-D1CD-312E-BD2E-F7C66343A417
RCTViewManagerModuleNameForClass
RCTSurfaceStageIsPreparing
RCTSurfaceStageIsPreparing
B7D9D0A6-2414-37F2-9D03-1A25A474E2CF
B7D9D0A6-2414-37F2-9D03-1A25A474E2CF
B7D9D0A6-2414-37F2-9D03-1A25A474E2CF
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
3A5F992A-D1CD-312E-BD2E-F7C66343A417
3A5F992A-D1CD-312E-BD2E-F7C66343A417
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
7BF01CFC-23F1-326A-AFD8-AD967FFECE28
UIApplicationMain
main
7BE2B757-3B3D-3E91-8CB7-74F3887660C7


Oddly, I can still modify the status bar but I still get the error.

"I am using the createNativeStackNavigator function from the react-navigation library, but I was using this import:
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from "react-native-screens/native-stack" which is not supported anymore.
I replaced it with this one:
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/native-stack" and it fixed the problem for me."

My issue was that I was trying to set statusBarStyle / statusBarColor, when having the presentation: "modal". In my case it turned out that I did not need them, so I could just remove them...
    <RootStack.Group
      screenOptions={{
        presentation: "modal",
        headerShown: false,
        navigationBarHidden: true,
        statusBarStyle: "light",
        statusBarColor: AppColors.colors.BackgroundMain,
        navigationBarColor: AppColors.colors.BackgroundMain,
      }}
    >

